# How can I get the scene polycount in python?

Tags: python, mesh, scripting, polycount

Is there any access in the python API to get the total scene (or object) polygon count?

This info is already displayed in the status bar, but is this info exposed in the python API or do I need to manually loop through all objects and count the faces?

[image: status bar]

Answer (score 10):

OK [twitter to the rescue](https://twitter.com/tobkum/status/1394246480882552833)!

Here's my solution:

`bpy.context.scene.statistics(bpy.context.view_layer)` gets you the same string as shown in the status bar, so to get the triangle count this just needs to be parsed:

```py
s = bpy.context.scene.statistics(bpy.context.view_layer)
tris = int(s.split("Tris:")[1].split(' ')[0].replace(',', ''))
```

This is obviously dependent on the view, so it only includes the visible objects in the current view layer.

If you only want to know the tris of a specific object you can hide everything else or just enter edit mode.

Comment: Was about to post that, beat me to it. ;)

Comment: Do you know of a way to get that while in edit mode on an object? In that mode the command returns the statistics for the selected objects only.